# What happens if I rebase after pushing?

Tags: git, rebase

I always hear that it's something scary and something I should never do. For example, here's how the pull dialog looks like in SourceTree:

[image]

So I'm curious, what would happen and how bad would it be if I had pushed changes, then rebased and pushed them again? And how to fix the repository if I'd break it this way?

Comment: The good news is that nothing is lost. You'd effectively just create a new branch with a lot of duplication with the existing one, and needless hassle for anyone that had pulled from the repository recently.

Comment: Rebasing a commit produces another commit that has the same content as the original commit but a different ID. Given the original commit was pushed and you forcibly push the new commit, the other developers that already pulled your original commit will now have duplicate commits (same changes in files but different IDs). This leads to confusion.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Nothing would happen, but your next push would be not accepted.

Unless you would force push. 
This would not break remote repository also, so it is also not that bad.

Things go bad when you have more people using this repo. 
Rewriting history can cause a bit of chaos for others who will pull new changes from remote. Especially if they do not have good knowledge of git.
There can be different things that might happen for person pulling rewritten remote branch depending on state of their local repository.

So if someone would work on feature X and you changed the code on which he based his changes, he might get at least upset to downright angry depending on how much of his work you made obsolete.

Comment: The good news is that the other guy can still base his changes on the branch as he saw it (nothing will be lost in their local repo), and even push that back. And one point, someone has to merge things together (and that should probably be the one who force-pushed).

Comment: @Thilo Yes but you still need at least 1 person in team that knows how to GIT. Otherwise I can imagine blaming GIT for eating the code, breaking the project, world hunger etc.

Comment: Yes, having someone (I'd say everyone) understand how git works would help :-)   For those that don't, stay away from `--force` and heed the warnings on the box.

Comment: As a by-the-by, I fatfingered a commit message.  Our CM people like us to include the associated Jira issue in the commit messages, and I was off-by-one.  This handy [tutorial on amending older commit messages](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-commit-message/)  tells you to reword to amend the commit message, then force push your changes.  I note it only that it is easy for people who screw things up to really screw things up.

Answer (score 4):

In the scenario you are listing in SourceTree, SourceTree rebases the local commits that haven't been pushed on top of the changes that you are pulling from the remote.

If you had already pushed changes before using THAT option, those changes wouldn't be rebased because they're already in the remote.

The only exception may be if you have multiple remotes, and have pushed changes to one remote, then do a pull/rebase from another - that could cause serious problems.

Whether you should rebase or not during a pull is a subject of debate. I'm not recommending it, but it is generally safe. https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2014/12/pull-request-merge-strategies-the-great-debate/