# how to remove merge commit from git history and make it one line?

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I made 3 changes in a local branch with 3 different commit each. The origin branch was ahead  by 1 commit so the two branchs have diverged. And instead of doing `git pull --rebase`, i did a `git pull` and then i did a `push` so the history now becomes not clean. So can anyone help me to remove the merge commit and clean the history?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens if I rebase after pushing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39098811/what-happens-if-i-rebase-after-pushing)

Comment: What does "not clean" history mean?

Comment: basically i should use rebase to integrate work of team members, but instead of that i did a mistake by doing a merge. so there was a merge commit wich appeared in the history. this is made the history not clean for me.